# Can a stuck case fan cause the system to freeze?

Tags: windows-7, freeze, fan

Recently, my computer freezes sometimes at random. The freeze has no bluescreen and Windows 7 does not even generate a memory dump, the screen is just still and it doesn't respond to my keyboard and mouse, so I can only hard reset it.

I just opened the case to check if there's anything wrong, I then discovered that a case fan is stuck by a wire, making it unable to spin. I touched its motor and found that it's a little bit hot.

Is this possible that a stuck case fan can (indirectly) cause the system to freeze?

Comment: I guess your about to find out :-)  Indirecly yes. likely to be the only reason you getting freezes is low, if your temps were going crasy because of it  higher.

Comment: If your system gets too hot (for whatever reason) it can shutdown. CPUs for example have a thermal cut-off. Yo can use a program such as [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) to monitor all kind of temperatures in your PC.

Comment: If it continues, check the Event Viewer for error messages. That may give you some idea what is causing issues if it is not temperature alone.